# Sencha Cmd using Compass.app for Windows, what is the PATH?

Tags: windows, extjs, path

Sencha Cmd using Compass.app for Windows, what is the Environment Variable PATH - to compass within compass.app?

Context:
Our development team previously runs sass through compass.app (windows version) for PC.
It is working well and we are now beginning to work with ExtJS and Sencha Cmd build utility.

When I run **sencha app build** I get the "compass not found" and this is because it is not recognizing the compass that exists within compass.app in the PATH.

Questions: 
*Does anyone have an example PATH to compass (on windows) for reference - so I can search for the target within compass.app?* In other words, I know how to set the Environment Variable, but I am having **difficulty finding what the equivalent target of compass that could reasonably exist within compass.app**.

Since I have compass.app working separately, I tried the sencha.cfg setting, *skip.sass=1*, but I noticed that this results in none of the CSS being moved to the build.

*Is there a setting that skips compass but still moves the css files over?*

*Overall, is it possible to use Sencha Cmd with Compass.app in this way?*

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Nash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin on github indicated that this is not an existing feature of CompassApp, but that they are considering it.

https://github.com/handlino/CompassApp/issues/117

At current it seems the solution remains installing ruby and gems for windows.

http://compass-style.org/install/

Comment: BTW, it was very easy to install #Ruby on #Windows here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/